# How to prove for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}} \geq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, induction

Should I do it by induction (I had a hard time trying this) or can I use something like that:

**Complementary Result**: Let $n \in\mathbb{N}$ and $p >0$. It will be true that $$\frac{p}{\sqrt{n}} \geq \frac{p}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq 0$$

**Proof**:  using multiplication monotonicity and multiplying all sides by $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ and then squaring all sides: $$\frac{p}{\sqrt{n}} \geq \frac{p}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq 0 \implies \sqrt{n+1}\cdot p \geq \sqrt{n} \cdot p \geq 0\implies (n+1)p^2 \geq np^2 \geq 0$$

Finally, multiplying all sides by $\frac{1}{p^2}$, we get $n+1\geq n \geq 0$, which is true.

Now, is this **CR** correct? And can we use it to prove the question?

Comment: +1 good work shown, nice presentation.  Only criticism : you have the implications **facing the wrong way**.  It is as if you wanted to prove that $R \Rightarrow S$ and instead, you proved that $S \Rightarrow R$.

Comment: I see now. To correct this one can start by implying $n+1 \geq n \geq 0$ and work through this until reaches the final statement $\frac{p}{\sqrt{n}} \geq \frac{p}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq 0$, right?

Comment: Yep.............

Comment: Why do you need the $p$?

Comment: I am using this result to prove a bigger result in which the upper term sometines $\neq1$ but is also positive.